# DATALOG references

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, db.databases, logic-programming

What are the best references for self study in DATALOG? I am particularly interested in expressive power, complexity results, evaluation methods, extensions of DATALOG with negation etc. Are there any books or papers that cover all these?

Comment: An important relatively recent complexity paper related to DATALOG that comes to my mind is (though perhaps you are looking for surveys only): A. Atserias.
On Sufficient Conditions for Unsatisfiability of Random Formulas,
Journal of the ACM, 51(2), pages 281-311, 2004.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of what you are looking for is well-covered in the survey

- Stefano Ceri, Georg Gottlob, and Letizia Tanca, *What you always wanted to know about Datalog (and never dared to ask)*, IEEE Transactions on Knowledge and Data Engineering **1** 146–166, 1989. ([link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/69.43410), [reprint](http://www.iai.uni-bonn.de/III/lehre/vorlesungen/DeduktiveDatenbanken/SS06/Downloads/CGT89.pdf))

and its references.  The field then went fairly quiet for a long time.

Recently various extensions to Datalog have been gaining a lot of attention, and the [Datalog 2.0 conference](http://datalog20.org/) in 2010 was well-attended.  I'm personally quite partial to the Datalog± family of extensions, since they allow several kinds of description logics to be captured in a well-behaved and well-understood fragment of classical logic:

- Andrea Calì, Georg Gottlob, and Thomas Lukasiewicz, *Datalog±: a unified approach to ontologies and integrity constraints*, ICDT 2009, 14–30. ([link](http://www.edbt.org/Proceedings/2009-StPetersburg/icdt/papers/p0014-Cali.pdf))

Answer (score 5):

The standard reference (more complete and up to date than the Ceri et al survey) is [Foundations of Databases](http://webdam.inria.fr/Alice/) by Abiteboul, Hull, and Vianu.  (Happily, Addison-Wesley has given the authors permission to post the PDFs online.)